# Ruby Loop Array and Create Hash for Each Array Object

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'd like to loop through an array and create a hash for each object in the array, then group all those hashes into an array of hashes.

Here's an example starting array for me:

```
urls = ["http://stackoverflow.com", "http://example.com", "http://foobar.com"]
```

Now let's say I'd like to have a hash for each of those URLs into an array like this:

```
urls =[ { 
'url' => "http://stackoverflow.com",
'dns_status' => "200",
'title' => "Stack Overflow"
},
{
'url' => "http://example.com",
'dns_status'=> "200",
'title' => "Example"
}
]
```

Leaving aside where I get the values for the `dns_status` and `title` keys in the example, I guess what I'm missing is how to loop through the original array and create a hash for each object...

I've played around with `inject`, `collect`, `map` and `each` and read through the docs but can't quite make sense of it or get anything to work.

Any recommendation? Will this be easier to accomplish with a class?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your help everyone. Figured this out and got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I am a bit confused at present. I understand you have an array (called urls), but what do you want to achieve? You wish to turn the array into an array of hashes instead?

Comment: Yes. I want to create a hash for each url in the array. The hash will have keys like :url and some other values which i'll be doing api lookups on later in the real script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something with each element of something enumerable and store the result in an array: that is what [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) does. Specify what you want in the block, like this:

```
urls = ["http://stackoverflow.com", "http://example.com", "http://foobar.com"]
p res = urls.map{|url| {"url"=>url, "dns_status"=>200, "title"=>url[7..-5]} }

#=> [{"url"=>"http://stackoverflow.com", "dns_status"=>200, "title"=>"stackoverflow"}, {"url"=>"http://example.com", "dns_status"=>200, "title"=>"example"}, {"url"=>"http://foobar.com", "dns_status"=>200, "title"=>"foobar"}]
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Works.

Comment: Come on, steen, no horizontal scrolling, please.

Answer (score 0):

"what I'm missing is how to loop through the original array and create a hash for each object..."

```
urls = [
  "http://stackoverflow.com",
  "http://example.com",
  "http://foobar.com"
]
urls.each {|entry|
  puts entry
}
```

You could use **.map!** for instance. But I am still not sure what your target result ought to be. How about this?

```
urls.map! {|entry|
  { 'url' => entry, 'dns_status' => "200", 'title' => "Stack Overflow"}
}
urls # => [{"url"=>"http://stackoverflow.com", "dns_status"=>"200", "title"=>"Stack Overflow"}, {"url"=>"http://example.com", "dns_status"=>"200", "title"=>"Stack Overflow"}, {"url"=>"http://foobar.com", "dns_status"=>"200", "title"=>"Stack Overflow"}]
```

Yikes, the result is hard to see. It is this:

```
[
{
  "url"=>"http://stackoverflow.com",
  "dns_status"=>"200",
  "title"=>"Stack Overflow"
},
{
  "url"=>"http://example.com",
  "dns_status"=>"200",
  "title"=>"Stack Overflow"
},
{
  "url"=>"http://foobar.com",
  "dns_status"=>"200",
  "title"=>"Stack Overflow"
}
]
```

Obviously, you need to still supply the proper content for title,
but you did not give this in your original question so I could not
fill it in.

Comment: why `map!` and not `map`?

Comment: Not only does `map!` destroy the original array, but @steenslag has already offered a solution that uses `map`.  The addition of the bang is questionable justification for a separate answer.  Moreover, `"Stack Overflow"` is not the value of `title` for all elements.